# How to pass express errors message to Angular view?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I am asking because if javascript is disabled then server side validation will work.

Comment: if javascript is disabled, then how are you using angularjs?

Comment: I am checking initially whether js is enabled or not

Comment: your question makes no sense.  if JavaScript is disabled, Angular won't load, so there won't be any Angular view to use server side validation with.

Comment: @McVenco please don't search for a common typo and correct only that. At best you're wasting reviewers' time and at worst you're gaming the system.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you the next approaches:

1. Add a `noscript` tag in your html to manage a browser with javascript disabled. If you think a little, all Angular behaviour depends directly of JS, so, if it's disabled then your page won't starts nor function.
2. Check the [express error handling docs](http://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)
3. Add a custom ErrorHandler and ErrorExceptions to send in every particular case and a generic error when an unexpected situations happens and send it with `next` express function and to handle in promise `catch`
4. Always add frontend and backend validations, this is know like validation in deep, that means that you verify a valid, correct and permitted data.

Hope this can help you.

Regards.